# Is this photo of Gavrilo Princip or Nedeljko Čabrinović?

Tags: world-war-one

[image]
It seems most websites say this is Gavrilo Princip who shot Franz Ferdinand, but some say it is Nedeljko Čabrinović who threw the bomb at him. I was wondering if anyone knew for sure?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please add a reference for each of your assertions and I'll probably upvote this.

Comment: The identity of this person is disputed. See [File:Gavrilo Princip captured in Sarajevo 1914.jpg](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Gavrilo_Princip_captured_in_Sarajevo_1914.jpg).

Answer (score 1):

First Čabrinović threw this bomb. Franz Ferdinand was not hurt but one of the guards was wounded. They chased Čabrinović to the river. Some time later (after an official reception) Franz Ferdinand decided to visit the wounded guard in the hospital, before leaving Sarajevo. On the way to the hospital, the driver lost his way, and had to stop and back. At this moment Princip made his shots.
Evidently this is a photo of Princip when he was caught.

Comment: Do you have a source for that?  I've seen several sources (for [example](https://www.theguardian.com/books/2015/jul/14/tim-butcher-first-world-war-began-the-trigger-hunting-the-assassin-who-brought-the-world-to-war) ) that suggest the picture is actually of Ferdinand Behr, who was mistakenly arrested following the shooting.

Answer (score 1):

This is [FERDINAND BEHR](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Gavrilo_Princip_captured_in_Sarajevo_1914.jpg). He was defending Princip after the assassination. That's why he's arrested too. From Wikipedia:

> This picture is often said to depict the arrest of en:Gavrilo Princip,
>   although several scholars say that it depicts the arrest of Ferdinand
>   Behr, a bystander who was initially suspected of involvement in the
>   assassination.

Comment: Welcome to History:SE.  Sources to support that assertion would greatly improve your answer.  You  might find it helpful to review our [site tour](https://history.stackexchange.com/tour) and [Help Centre](https://history.stackexchange.com/help) and, in particular, [How to write a good answer](https://history.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: You may be right according to 'some scholars', e.g. David James Smith, [*One Morning In Sarajevo*](https://books.google.com.ph/books?id=GzsnSU9J5sAC&redir_esc=y), but I don't see any reference to "He was defending Princip after the assassination. That's why he's arrested too."